# Blockchain.info not actual?

Tags: blockchain.info

I'm really new to Bitcoining. I've made my own wallet at blockchain.info, and then I decided to get some "free" bitcoins by watchings ads or something. This worked. At leas when i login at Microwallet.org with the Adress I have from Blockchain. 
On Microwallet there's displayed my account balance of xxx Bitcoin. But on Blockchain.info (logged in with the same address, of course), my Account balance is 0.

Why?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. :) Do you actually mean "login" or do you just check the balance of an address? If you log in at both services, how did you achieve that both services manage the same address for you? Also, perhaps you want to improve your title: Blockchain is an important component of the Bitcoin network, while Blockchain.info is a service that named itself unfortunately after the former. The title made me think of the network component, while you seem to be talking about the service in the question. You can edit your own post in order to improve it.

Comment: Ok, edited it. I mean i logged in in Blockchain.info and i checked my balance in Microwallet (read only)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lorenz,
Blockchain.info is one of the,  if not the most "actual"  bitcoin wallets you can get.  It's streaming and constantly revised data plotting is also the industry standard,  although it is incomplete.

Most of the spoofy little faucets you find Will in fact earn you some mbtc,  or micro bitcoin,  however,  just because they have deposited into a wallet of their own creation and their own design,  this does not obligate them in any way to connect with the blockchain.info main chain.

This is because mostly you get what you pay for,  and you work for what you're paid. So,  watching videos and doing this or that is all well and stupid,  and it also has nothing to do with earning money. . 00000001 is called a satoshi,  after bitcoins pseudonymous creator.  You will be lucky to have as many as just a handful of these doing what you're describing and also successfully redeeming them by TRANSFERING THEM to legitimate wallet service like a blockchain.info.